# Errors while installing Cairo on Julia 0.3.0

Tags: cairo, julia

While trying to install `Images` and `ImageView`, the package manager tried to install Cairo, and failed. This was the error message:

```
[ ERROR: Cairo ]
None of the selected providers could satisfy library group cairo
Use BinDeps.debug(package_name) to see available providers

while loading C:\Users\Peter\.julia\v0.3\Cairo\deps\build.jl, in 
expression starting on line 136
```

I searched Google for the exact phrase "None of the selected providers could satisfy library group cairo", and there was exactly one hit at [this website](https://www.marshut.net/kmrqrn/pkg-add-cairo-fails.html), where a user named Julio Valdes reported exactly the same problem.

Strangely enough, he posted his question 3 hours before I wrote this, which makes me suspect that the error might be due to some sort of breaking change that occurred very recently. However, I am not well-versed in Julia development, so this is just a guess.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong? Is there more information which I should provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely this issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/BinDeps.jl/issues/104

Things like this are probably better to report on the julia-users Google Group/mailing list than on SO, most Julia package devs don't follow the julia-lang SO tag too closely.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I posted a link to this question on the issues thread you cited. Is there a workaround I could use in the mean time?

Comment: Eventually I got it to work on 0.3.0 64-bit, thanks!